# Does a proning opportunity attack end movement in the square a creature was moving from?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, movement, opportunity-attack, prone

For the party I DM for, one of the Minotaur players has an nearly absurd (judgement call) feat called **Opportunity Gore**.  Opportunity Gore lets a Minotaur use his racial power **Goring Charge** over and over again as an **opportunity attack**.

When Goring Charge hits, it knocks the target **prone**.  So this leads to a slew of questions about how proning affects a creature in mid-movement.   I think there are some rules for this situation but I can't remember where they are.

The primary question is: Does an opportunity proning immediately end movement and the move action in the triggering start square?

If not, what would happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they are knocked prone in the starting square. An opportunity action is a type of interrupt and thus happens before the move takes place.

The move action is then lost as they can no longer walk/run/climb and must crawl.

I strongly suggest employing parties of dwarven monsters.

Answer (score -1):

The creature would trigger the opportunity attack when leaving the minotaur reach unless the feat states otherwise (like polearm master does). opportunity attacks are special kind of reactions that interrupt their trigger, normal reactions take place after trigger. so the creature lands prone in the starting square. however, the creature is still on its turn, and if it had enough movement left it could stand up (needs half movement, not an action)and use its remaining actions, movement, bonus actions etc. if any are left. Disengage as action or as bonus action (rogue cunning action) or other things could help your encounters, readying actions to trigger at precise positions, some spells, etc.

Comment: This answer seems to be geared towards 5th Edition D&D, while the question is for 4th Edition. Unfortunately, most of what's said in this answer isn't applicable to the earlier version.