# Does making an Opportunity Attack with Lashing Flail cancel the target's movement?

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack, forced-movement, move-action

Lashing flail (Martial Power 2, pg.143):

> Whenever you use a flail to hit an enemy with a melee basic attack, you can slide that enemy 1 square.

If an enemy tries to move past me while I have this feat and a flail, and I hit them with my OA and slide them 1 square back the way they came, does it still get the rest of its movement (which could be 4+ squares remaining)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they can continue moving if they have any movement left.

> An opportunity action takes place before the target finishes its action. After the opportunity attack, the creature resumes its action. [[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=331)]

In order to stop moving you need something like a Fighter's Combat Superiority that specifically stops them from moving farther with that action.

> An enemy hit by your opportunity attack stops moving, if a move provoked the attack. If the enemy still has actions remaining, it can use them to resume moving. [[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/class.aspx?id=3)]

Comment: If the attack knocked them prone instead of sliding them (with Flail Expertise), would they still be able to crawl (moving half of their remaining movement, rounded down)?

Comment: @1000thSon That's a different question, and is answered [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/16232/). But yes, knocking a creature prone mid-movement ends the triggering move action, because "crawl" is a different at-will move action choice than "walk". Similar to the quoted text from Combat Superiority, if the enemy has actions remaining it can use them to crawl.